# Pathfinding for 2D tile map for multiple goals

Tags: c++, path-finding

I'm trying to create a simple grid-based game in C++. The pathfinding is necessary part of it. I've been searching, but there isn't what I am exactly looking for.

The rules are simple. There is a map. The size generally doesn't exceed 100 x 100 tiles. 1 is a floor tile, 0 is a wall. Diagonal movement isn't allowed, so there are only 4 directions from each grid. However there are mostly more than one goal. I'd like to find the way to nearest one. Remember that we can't just calculate, which one is the nearest by distance formula. The goal with shorter distance can has longer way, because of walls. I think using one of known algorithms and repeating, for each goal isn't a good idea, because it will slow.

What's your opinion? What should I do?

Comment: A* on a 100 by 100 grid in 4-connected space will be quite fast (remember to use Manhattan Distance!). Your best bet really is to simply run it on all of them and compare final path lengths, as there is no way to figure out which goal is 'closest' by your definition without already knowing the optimal path to that goal. If your map is static, you can improve efficiency even further by re-encoding it as a graph where verticies are connected cells (think hallways) and nodes are branches in the path so you have fewer states to traverse.

Comment: If you use the same map to do pathfinding many times, I would consider to precalculate the distance from each field to each other field (excluding the walls of course)

Comment: @tobi303: That's insanely expensive O(N*N) and often not needed. Take the 100x100 map; you'd need O(100x100x100x100) distances. For may reasonable graphs (and this grid-one will be) it's sufficient to have a far smaller number of "shortcuts" that are common. E.g. if you can identify a cul-de-sac, you just need the distance from each point in the cul-de-sac to the neck point.

Comment: @MSalters If you use the same map and do really many path-findings, then if you precalculate all distances, the expense of a single path-finding is practically O(1). You just have to look it up in a list. This pre-calculation could be done "pre-runtime", so I dont understand why you call it "insanely expensive". Especially, the tricks you mention can aswell applied when distances are precalculated.

Comment: @MSalters Also, I would guess, that the number of non-wall tiles is much lower than 100x100. If it was just 100x100, there would be no need for a sophisticated algorithm. Of course, if the game uses a different map each time, precalculating wont make sense, but it really would be "insanely expensive".

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a big problem. Add a hypothetical end node E with distance 1 to all real goals, and search the best path to E. The one-but-last node on the path will be one of those real goals.

Comment: It would be helpful to state how this would work with the huristic portion of an algorithm like A* (or if it wouldn't). How do you calculate the huristic distance to a virtual position that will guide the search in a meaningful way?

Comment: @aruisdante: Same way as with the real path: `H(E) = 1 + min(H(goals))`.

Comment: Wouldn't that, as defined, essentially always bias the search towards the physically closest goal, rather than the one of shortest path length? It clearly would work, but I wonder if it's actually going to be faster than just doing A* on each goal individually. I imagine it would depend greatly on map configuration. But probably in most cases would be faster.

Comment: Ah wait, I was thinking it would be statically calculated. Of course if you calculate `min(H(goals))` freshly at every state it will always be biasing you towards the closest goal to that state in the search, which is almost certainly the correct thing to do.

Comment: @You just need to calculate it for the nodes you encounter in the A* search (lazily), but once you've calculated it you can reuse it until the goals change.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others. Consider encoding to graph and maybe best is to preacalculate this for all tiles. I would go basically for Floyd-Warshall algorithm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

A* is an algorithm that can be used to do pathfinding on 2D grids.
[Here's a good simple A* tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

While you could run the algorithm several times, for each goal, an alternative would be to use an algorithm "Dijkstra's Algorithm", that unlike A* expands evenly in every direction, until all goals are found and select the one with the best result.

Comment: A small nitpick, Dijkstra's expands evenly *based on cost of path*, not number of nodes. Of course if all nodes the same cost to traverse these are equivalent. A* is simply Dijkstra's with the addition of a bias to moving 'towards' the goal by effectively adding the distance to goal from a node to the cost of traversing it (making the cost of traversing nodes that move you towards the goal 'cheaper'). If you set the heuristic cost weight to 0 in A*, you get Dijkstra's. If you set the path cost weight to 0 in A* you get essentially a Depth First Search.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick that may help with this problem: Use A* to search from all goals simultaneously to the start and then reverse the path. It's simpler than calculating the minimum Manhattan distance to every goal in every step or adding extra nodes to the graph.

Since A* maintains a list of candidates for the least-cost path via the OPEN list, you can simply insert all goal tiles into that open list. Due to the open list being a priority queue, A* will then find the least-cost path from any of the goals by trying heuristically close goals first and only switching to goals that are further away once it becomes clear that the path to them is less costly. This gives you a path from the best goal to the start position, which you then simply reverse to get a path from start to goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a pathfinding precomputation software for 2d tiled maps having game

It is in C# but certainly could help you or the ones who is looking for an answer to this question

Both software development video and the source code is available

Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRTA0iLjv6M

Source code : https://github.com/FurkanGozukara/pathfinding-2d-tile-map

The coded software is already being used in the free to play game MonsterMMORPG : https://www.monstermmorpg.com/

I can't claim it is the best or most optimal way though it works quite well. Also for the video title I am inspired from this question