# Simple Pathfinder in c++

Tags: c++, path-finding

I'm working on a simple pathfinder. I've a small grid-based map.
'1' is a floor
'0' is a wall
'G' is one of the goals

Features:
- there isn't diagonal movement
- path cost always equals 1
- there can be many goals

My full code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int MapWidth = 10, MapHeight = 10;
//       Y pos      X pos
char Map[MapHeight][MapWidth] = {
    { '1', '1', 'G', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'G' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '1', '1', '1', 'G', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' }
};

struct Pos
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};

bool PosIsUsed(vector <Pos> Position, int Y, int X)
{
    for (vector <Pos>::iterator it = Position.begin(); it != Position.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->X == X && it->Y == Y)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void SearchNext(int Y, int X, vector <Pos> Position)
{
    Pos NewStep = { X, Y };
    Position.push_back(NewStep);
    //North
    if (Y >= 1 && !PosIsUsed(Position, Y - 1, X))
    {
        vector <Pos> NewPosition = Position;
        switch (Map[Y - 1][X])
        {
        case '1':
            SearchNext(Y - 1, X, NewPosition);
            break;
        case 'G':
            printf("Found!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    //East
    if (X + 1 < MapWidth && !PosIsUsed(Position, Y, X + 1))
    {
        vector <Pos> NewPosition = Position;
        switch (Map[Y][X + 1])
        {
        case '1':
            SearchNext(Y, X + 1, NewPosition);
            break;
        case 'G':
            printf("Found!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    //Soth
    if (Y + 1 < MapHeight && !PosIsUsed(Position, Y + 1, X))
    {
        vector <Pos> NewPosition = Position;
        switch (Map[Y + 1][X])
        {
        case '1':
            SearchNext(Y + 1, X, NewPosition);
            break;
        case 'G':
            printf("Found!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    //West
    if (X >= 1 && !PosIsUsed(Position, Y, X - 1))
    {
        vector <Pos> NewPosition = Position;
        switch (Map[Y][X - 1])
        {
        case '1':
            SearchNext(Y, X - 1, NewPosition);
            break;
        case 'G':
            printf("Found!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    vector <Pos> Pos;
    SearchNext(9, 9, Pos); //We start here (Pos [9][9])
    printf("End\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

There's a problem. It just never ends. Could you tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

## Edit:

I switched X and Y params order in *SearchNext* function. After this change, program displays the infinity "Found!".

Working code (not mine):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


const char FLOOR = '1' ;
const char WALL  = '0' ;
const char GOAL  = 'G' ;

const int MapWidth = 10, MapHeight = 10;
//       Y pos      X pos
char Map[MapHeight][MapWidth] = {
    { '1', '1', 'G', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'G' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '1', '1', '1', 'G', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' }
};

struct Pos
{
    short x,y;
    Pos operator + ( Pos p ) const { return Pos(x+p.x,y+p.y); }
    bool operator < ( Pos p ) const { return ( y==p.y ) ? (x<p.x) : (y<p.y) ; }
    bool operator != ( Pos p ) const { return ( y!=p.y ) || (x!=p.x) ; }
    Pos(short x=0,short y=0) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

bool valid(Pos p) { return p.x>=0 && p.x<MapWidth && p.y>=0 && p.y<MapHeight; }

enum Dir { d_beg, d_up=d_beg, d_rg, d_dn, d_lf, d_end };

Pos deltas[d_end] = { {0,-1}, {+1,0}, {0,+1}, {-1,0} };

Dir& operator ++ ( Dir& d ) { d = (Dir) ( 1+(int)d ) ; return d; }

Dir other(Dir d)
{
    switch(d)
    {
    case d_up: return d_dn;
    case d_rg: return d_lf;
    case d_dn: return d_up;
    case d_lf: return d_rg;
    default: return d_end;
    }
}

struct SearchMapItem
{
    bool traversble;
    bool goal;
    bool visited;
    int cost_here;
    Dir came_from;
    bool paths[d_end];
};

map<Pos,SearchMapItem> search_map;
typedef map<Pos,SearchMapItem>::iterator SMII;

void MakeMap()
{
    search_map.clear();
    Pos p;
    for(p.y=0;p.y<MapHeight;++p.y) for(p.x=0;p.x<MapWidth;++p.x) 
    {
        SearchMapItem smi;
        smi.visited = false;
        smi.cost_here = -1;
        smi.came_from = d_end;
        if( Map[p.y][p.x] == WALL )
        {
            smi.traversble = false;
        }
        else if( Map[p.y][p.x] == GOAL )
        {
            smi.traversble = true;
            smi.goal = true;
        }
        else if( Map[p.y][p.x] == FLOOR )
        {
            smi.traversble = true;
            smi.goal = false;
            for( Dir d = d_beg; d != d_end; ++d )
            {
                Pos p2 = p + deltas[d];
                smi.paths[d] = valid(p2) && (Map[p2.y][p2.x] != WALL) ;
            }
        }
        search_map[p] = smi;
    }
}

void FindGoalFrom( Pos start )
{
    vector<SMII> found;

    {
        SMII smii = search_map.find(start);

        if(smii==search_map.end()) { cout << "starting outside map\n"; return; }
        if(smii->second.goal) { cout << "already at target\n"; return; }
        if(!smii->second.traversble) { cout << "starting in a wall\n"; return; }

        smii->second.visited = true;
        smii->second.cost_here = 0;
        found.push_back(smii);
    }

    int cost_so_far = 0;
    bool did_find = false;

    while(!did_find)
    {

        vector<SMII> candidates;

        for( SMII smii : found )
        {
            for( Dir d = d_beg; d != d_end; ++d )
            {
                if( ! smii->second.paths[d] ) continue;
                Pos p = smii->first + deltas[d];
                if(!valid(p)) continue;
                SMII cand = search_map.find(p);
                if(cand==search_map.end()) continue;
                if(cand->second.visited) continue;
                cand->second.came_from=d;
                candidates.push_back(cand);
            }
        }

        ++cost_so_far;

        if( candidates.empty() ) break;

        for( SMII smii : candidates )
        {
            smii->second.visited = true;
            smii->second.cost_here = cost_so_far;
            found.push_back(smii);
            if( smii->second.goal ) { did_find = true; break; }
        }

    }

    if( ! did_find ) { cout << "no goal reachable\n"; return; }

    SMII pos = found.back();

    vector<Dir> path;

    while( pos->first != start )
    {
        Dir d = pos->second.came_from;
        path.push_back(d);
        Pos p = pos->first + deltas[ other(d) ];
        pos = search_map.find(p);
    }

    for( auto itr = path.rbegin(); itr != path.rend(); ++itr )
    {
        const char* dir_names[] = { "Up", "Right", "Down", "Left" } ;
        cout << "Walk " << dir_names[*itr] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Then you are at goal in total " << to_string(cost_so_far) << " steps" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MakeMap();

    FindGoalFrom( Pos(5,9) );

    cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

Comment: Or maybe it does end, but it takes an incredibly long time before it ends.

Comment: Please read [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and then come back with a specific question once you've followed the recommendations there in.

Comment: @immibis Halting problem win!

Comment: Considering that a `Pos` type has already been written in this code, it would be prudent to *use it* where it's applicable.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are giving the issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say there are at average 2.5 directions to choose from, then 
your algorithm will take 2.5<sup>n</sup> steps to complete, where n is the 
number of squares. That will be an incredible large number, even 
for fairly small n. You need to look into [Djikstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

This is assuming you eventually want to find the cheapest route to 
a goal, not just any route.

Comment: Or they could use any of the methods recommended in the [last question they asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840102/pathfinding-for-2d-tile-map-for-multiple-goals/28840265#comment45950333_28840265)

Comment: if you want to cheat, look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cedb4a0af0360dd1

Answer (score 5):

You're switching the order of X and Y in the recursive calls to SearchNext.

In general you can analyze these kinds of problems in a debugger or by adding trace output. You would have found the problem on the second call to SearchNext: "huh, why is X equal to 8 while I subtracting 1 from Y?".

Comment: Thanks. I changed it. One step forward. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Another step forward is to add tracing: add printf at every step to see what's happening.

Answer (score -2):

Or maybe write 2 dimension map with availbe places to mow, and use straight line for direction, and then according to direction hide places what are far from that line. This way you will live with places availbe to go.